# what happens when a domain functional level is set lower than forest functional level?

Tags: domain, active-directory

For. e.g When a forest functional level is set to windows 2008, what happens if a domain functional level is set to windows 2003? My question is, why does the rule says domain FL should be >= forest FL?

Comment: there would be some errors since domain functional level must be set to a level greater than forest functional level. can anyone tell me why does that happens? why can't we set random functional levels?

Comment: The answer makes more sense if you think about the fact that you can have multiple domains within a forest. If you upgrade the forest functional level, then no new domains in that forest can run at a lower functional level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Microsoft, this is not possible. From TechNet: [*Understanding Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) Functional Levels*](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(WS.10).aspx):

> When you deploy a new forest, you are prompted to set the forest functional level and then set the domain functional level. You cannot set the domain functional level to a value that is lower than the forest functional level.

Forest takes precedence as the *minimum* functional level of each domain in the forest:

> You can set the domain functional level to a value that is higher than the forest functional level. For example, if the forest functional level is Windows Server 2003, you can set the domain functional level to Windows Server 2003 or higher.

Comment: Is it like when we set to 2008 (forest level) can't we see any option below 2008 when we create a domain?

Comment: @user2490241 Correct. The forest functional level must be equal or greater than the domain level.

Comment: @NathanC [you've got it in reverse](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(WS.10).aspx), the *domain* level must be equal or greater than the forest level

Comment: @BigHomie Bah...oops :p